# Create infinite loop in jquery and effect like heart beat

Tags: jquery, web, frontend

I want to create infinite loop which has an effect on the `div` element like a heart beat. This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!($('div').hasClass("beat"))) {
    $('div').addClass('beat')
  } else {
    $('div').removeClass("beat")
  }
});
```

```css
#div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
.beat {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition-duration: 2s;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
```

This is my code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23vdoq9m/) but it has problem. Please give me a solution. Thanks.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: It would be a much better idea to do this using CSS animation. Here's the first hit in google: http://codepen.io/jlong/pen/KBhDf

Comment: @guradio please see my jsfiddle. It not working

Comment: @Rory McCrossan yes this is better idea. Thank you. So i using css keyframe animation

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with [`setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers), but it's probably easiest to do with a [CSS keyframe animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations).

Answer (score 1):

I have used jquery `on` to fetch `transitionend` events. However I agree, using CSS animations would be a better approach.

```
$("body").on("webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend", "div", function(event) {
   toggleFun(); // toggles classes.
});
```

Please refer this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23vdoq9m/2/).

Comment: Thank you, yes this is working but according to @Rory McCrossan comment CSS animation is better idea.

Answer (score 0):

When I was messing with your code, the thing that interfered was the CSS transition time. Because your JS code calls the next step (add or remove class) before the animation is finished.

One way to deal with that is the `.on('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {})` method.

But because I am not too familiar with transition ends myself and it is more trial and error, I went with a `.setTimeout()` in a self invoking function. For that I removed the transition time from the CSS and changed the JS.

```
#div {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 250px;
}

.beat {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    background: blue;
}



$( document ).ready(function() {
    function heartbeat() {
        setTimeout(function(){                //start setTimeout
            $('#div').toggleClass('beat');    //add or remove class .beat
            heartbeat();                      //and call the function again
        },500);                               //every half second
    }
    heartbeat();                              //CPR - start the heartbeat
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You use effects of animation for simulation hear beats.

```js
$.extend($.easing, {
  heartBeat: function(k, time, start_value = 0, end_value = 1, duration) {
    if (k < 0.3) return Math.pow(k, 4) * 49.4;
    else if (k < 0.4) return (9 * k) - 2.3;
    else if (k < 0.5) return (-13 * k) + 6.5;
    else if (k < 0.6) return (4 * k) - 2;
    else if (k < 0.7) return 0.4;
    else if (k < 0.75) return (4 * k) - 2.4;
    else if (k < 0.8) return (-4 * k) + 3.6;
    else if (k >= 0.8) return 1 - Math.sin(Math.acos(k));
  },
  heartIn: function(k, time, start_value, end_value, duration) {
    return $.easing.heartBeat(k, time, start_value, end_value, duration);
  },
  heartOut: function(k, time, start_value, end_value, duration) {
    return end_value - $.easing.heartBeat(1 - k, time, start_value, end_value, duration) + start_value;
  },
  heartInOut: function(k, time, start_value, end_value, duration) {
    if (time < duration / 2) return $.easing.heartIn(k, time, start_value, end_value, duration);
    return $.easing.heartOut(k, time, start_value, end_value, duration);
  },
});

function heartBeat($element, easing, sign = '+') {
  $element.animate({
    width: `${sign}=50`,
    height: `${sign}=50`,
  }, 2000, easing, function() {
    heartBeat($element, easing, sign === '+' ? '-' : '+');
  });
}

heartBeat($('#img1'), 'heartIn');
heartBeat($('#img2'), 'heartOut');
heartBeat($('#img3'), 'heartInOut');
```

```css
div img {
  content: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
  display: block;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div div {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div>
  <div>
    <img src="" id="img1">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="" id="img2">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="" id="img3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Result (static screen). Run code and you see animation.

[image]